# Rest Controller not seem to work in my Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I have a Springboot project I created by copying the libraries from mvn repository, not using SPRING INITLZR.

Anyway Springboot main seems to be working fine.
It's just that my Rest Controller is not displaying the message I want to.

**Main.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MovieInfoServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, MessagingException {
                
            SpringApplication.run(MovieInfoServiceApplication.class, args); 
        }
}
```

**RestController.class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MovieServiceRestController {

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        //@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9005")
        public String hello() {
            return "movie-service-api: hello from MovieServiceRestController";  
        }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>movie-info-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movie-info-service</name>
    <description>microservices about movie info</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is what I got when I access *"localhost:9005/hello"*

[image]

*Springboot logs*

```
2020-10-18 02:18:35.481  INFO 4347 --- [           main] com.gmailapijava.main.GmailAPIJavaMain   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-18 02:18:38.779  INFO 4347 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e708c1d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-18 02:18:39.142  INFO 4347 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-10-18 02:18:40.286  INFO 4347 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9005 (http)
2020-10-18 02:18:40.307  INFO 4347 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-18 02:18:40.307  INFO 4347 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-10-18 02:18:41.175  INFO 4347 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-18 02:18:41.176  INFO 4347 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5020 ms
2020-10-18 02:18:42.329  INFO 4347 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-18 02:18:43.369  INFO 4347 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9005 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-18 02:18:43.391  INFO 4347 --- [           main] com.gmailapijava.main.GmailAPIJavaMain   : Started GmailAPIJavaMain in 10.504 seconds (JVM running for 14.339)
2020-10-18 02:18:56.903  INFO 4347 --- [nio-9005-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-18 02:18:56.905  INFO 4347 --- [nio-9005-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-18 02:18:56.919  INFO 4347 --- [nio-9005-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 14 ms
```

Comment: Could you please put your package structure here.

Comment: Add your spring boot logs

Comment: It must be due to the package structure. Please follow https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code. This says you should keep the main class at root package and everything underneath. Otherwise you have to write manual @ComponentScan

Comment: package structure is missing

Comment: You use @Requestmapping with / and Getmapping again with a /. Remove the requestmapping or the/ in the getmapping

Answer (score 0):

```
SpringApplication.run(GmailAPIJavaMain.class, args);
```

should be

```
SpringApplication.run(MovieInfoServiceApplication.class, args);
```

Also check if the controller package is getting scanned.

Comment: sorry that was a typo from one of my working projects. Again springboot runs, but the problem is with my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
@RestController
public class MovieServiceRestController {

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        //@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9005")
        public String hello() {
            return "movie-service-api: hello from MovieServiceRestController";  
        }
}
```